# How to create an aspect on an Interface Method that extends from A "Super" Interface

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I have a service-layer Interface that extends from a base Interface; I would like to create a Pointcut around my service-layer Interface, but on one of the methods defined in the base Interface.

For instance.... I have a method in my base Interface called "save()", I put it in my base Interface since just all of my "child" Interfaces will provide "save" functionality.

I would like to create a PointCut on only one of my "child" interfaces for when my "save" gets called.

I created the pointcut like the following:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.xyz.someapp.ChildServiceInterface.save(..))")  
public void childServiceSavePointCut();
```

I then created a @Around advice around the above pointcut like the following:

```
@Around("childServiceSavePointCut()")
public void doMyAdvice()....
```

where "ChildServiceInterface" extends another Interface which has the "save()" method defined.

My Advice never runs... I debugged my code and do not see my Advice in the list of Advisors for my target service.

Am I way off base thinking this will work, or am I implementing it incorrectly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this pointcut instead.

```
within(com.xyz.someapp.ChildServiceInterface+) && execution(* save(..))
```

The `+` indicates a [subtype pattern](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/quick-typePatterns.html).

Answer (score 1):

Or you can put pointcut on all the methods of that class using

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.xyz.someapp.ChildServiceInterface.*(..))")  
public void childServiceSavePointCut();
```

The `*` indicates all method type.

Answer (score 0):

This one helps me:

```
    @Pointcut(
        "@within(com.xyz.someapp.ChildServiceInterface) && execution(* save(..))"
    )
```