# Aspect on super interface method implemented in abstract super class

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop, pointcut

I have a problem quite similar to: [How to create an aspect on an Interface Method that extends from A "Super" Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958400), but my save method is in an abstract super class.

The structure is as follows -

Interfaces:

```
public interface SuperServiceInterface {
    ReturnObj save(ParamObj);
}

public interface ServiceInterface extends SuperServiceInterface {
    ...
}
```

Implementations:

```
public abstract class SuperServiceImpl implements SuperServiceInterface {
    public ReturnObj save(ParamObj) {
        ...
    }
}

public class ServiceImpl implements ServiceInterface extends SuperServiceImpl {
    ...
}
```

I want to inspect any calls made to the `ServiceInterface.save` method.

The pointcut I have currently looks like this:

```
@Around("within(com.xyz.api.ServiceInterface+) && execution(* save(..))")
public Object pointCut(final ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable {
}
```

It gets triggered when the save method is put into the `ServiceImpl`, but not when it is in the `SuperServiceImpl`.
What am I missing in my around pointcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to pointcut on the `ServiceInterface`, if I do it on `SuperServiceInterface` wouldn't it also intercept save calls on interfaces that also inherit from `SuperServiceInterface`?

Yes, but you can avoid that by restricting the `target()` type to `ServiceInterface` as follows:

```java
@Around("execution(* save(..)) && target(serviceInterface)")
public Object pointCut(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, ServiceInterface serviceInterface)
    throws Throwable
{
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples) examples:

> the execution of any method defined by the `AccountService` interface:
>   `execution(* com.xyz.service.AccountService.*(..))`

In your case it should work as follows:

`execution(* com.xyz.service.SuperServiceInterface.save(..))`

Comment: I just want to pointcut on the `ServiceInterface`, if I do it on `SuperServiceInterface` wouldn't it also intercept save calls on interfaces that also inherit from `SuperServiceInterface`?

Comment: Try `execution(* com.xyz.service.ServiceInterface.save(..))`?

Comment: This does not get intercepted, possibly because the save is in the interface. I tried `execution(* com.xyz.service.ServiceInterface+.save(..))` aswell, but still was not triggered.

If the interface specifies save and the service implements save, this pointcut works.

Comment: I didn't tested it! I will try it in a dummy setup.